# How to Emulate hardware menu button

Tags: vanilla-ui

I have the [Sound Manager app](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=sound+manager&fdid=com.roozen.SoundManagerv2) . The app dates back to Android 2.2 and needs a hardware menu button  press to launch its menu .

Can I emulate the hardware menu button on my KitKat 4.4 device , so that I can see the menu?

Comment: Usually on Android 4.x above, there is a menu soft-button on lower right (beside "recent apps") for apps without Action Bar (read also [the official Android blog about this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html))

Comment: @andrewt Does your suggestion mean that if I simply recompile the sources with a recent SDK, without patching them, I will be given a soft button in the bottom right?

Comment: That's what I've been experiencing with legacy apps on newer Android. If you feel comfortable with compiling code, then updating the min\target SDK will either give the soft-button or even add the Action Bar (with overflow menu). But I can't guarantee if it will always work like that.

Comment: @andrew-t Thanks I will try that. Pls make your really helpful comments into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Samsung SM-J100H (Android KitKat 4.4.4), I can get the effect I want with a *long press on the App Switch hardware button*. I tested it in two apps:

On Sound Manager app, the menu slides out from the bottom of the screen.

On the Stack Exchange app, an 'Ask Question' button pops up across the bottom of the screen (but only in portrait orientation.)

Answer (score 1):

Apps that could either customize the navigation bar or generate another way of navigation would get it done; however, I've yet to seen one emulating MENU key without requiring root permissions.

[LMT Launcher](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150) is the app of this type I've been using - it hides a pie-shaped control tray into the edge(s) of your screen that you can activate by swiping from the edge, and contains not just regular navigation keys like BACK, HOME, MENU but also custom keypresses (e.g. POWER) and actions.